# Gitlab CI doesn't work with private image in Gitlab Registry

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have an image `gitlab.com/arxeiss/deployer` and project `gitlab.com/arxeiss/my-project` with `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
deploy:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/arxeiss/deployer
  stage: build
```

When I push to origin, pipeline works and image is pulled successfully. But when someone else pushes, who doesn't have access to deployer this error is thrown: `Error response from daemon: pull access denied for registry.gitlab.com/arxeiss/deployer, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'`

I have found in [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-an-image-from-a-private-container-registry) that I need `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` and the way [how to set it up](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#determining-your-docker_auth_config-data). But that means, I have to put auth token from `docker login` and `~/.docker/config.json` into CI/CD Variables.

But that is assigned to my account. So someone can use it and if I reset password etc. it stops working. Is there different way how to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don’t want to use your regular credentials, you can use a personal access token or deploy token instead - see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/#authenticating-to-the-gitlab-container-registry).

That way it’ll still work if you change your password and, as a bonus, you can revoke it without changing your regular password.

Comment: So instead of my credentials I put deploy token into the JSON and it will works same? This is awesome. I will try it when get to PC

Comment: As long as the token has the right permissions, yes.

Comment: Perfect, it works! When I created Deploy Token with `read_registry` I got Token Username and Password. Those I had to convert into Basic Auth and put into JSON (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#determining-your-docker_auth_config-data - Second Way). And `-n` switch after `echo` is very important!